# Vsphere 8.0 4k block size NVMeoF register device fail

Tags: vmware, esxi, nvme, vsphere

I have encounter a NVMe-oF problem.

I have tried to use NVMe-oF drive with 4K block size through TCP as datastore.
And after doing command "esxcli nvme fabrics connect -a  -i <ip_addresses> -p <port_number> -s <subsystem_nqn>. The device did not show up and cannot be selected when creating datastore.

The related messages from vmkernel.log as below:

```
2022-10-14T02:57:45.566Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDeviceIO: 10314: QErr is correctly set to 0x0 for device eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826.
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z Wa(180) vmkwarning: cpu4:262523)WARNING: NvmeScsi: 196: SCSI opcode 0x1a (0x4548c1b979c0) on path vmhba66:C0:T0:L0 to namespace eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826 failed with NVMe error status: 0x2 translating to SCSI error H:0x0
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z Wa(180) vmkwarning: cpu4:262523)WARNING: D:0x2 P:0x0 Valid sense data: 0x5 0x24 0x0
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z Wa(180) vmkwarning: cpu4:262174)WARNING: ScsiDeviceIO: 4422: ModeSense 0x1a request failed - blocking page:0x1c subpage:0x2 eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDeviceIO: 10821: Could not detect setting of sitpua for device eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Error Not supported.
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 2875: Failing registration of device 'eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826': Unsupported device attributes isLocal:0, isSSD:1, isNVME:1 isNmpOrHppPlugin:1
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5260: Failed to Unregister 'REPORTED LUNS DATA CHANGED' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5270: Failed to Unregister 'MODE PARAMETERS CHANGED' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5280: Failed to Unregister 'CAPACITY DATA HAS CHANGED' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5290: Failed to Unregister 'ASYMMETRIC ACCESS STATE CHANGED' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5300: Failed to Unregister 'INQUIRY PARAMETERS CHANGED' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5310: Failed to register for 'TARGET MICRO CODE CHANGED' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5320: Failed to Unregister 'POWER ON RESET' unit attention for device:eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826. Reason: Not found
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)ScsiDevice: 5392: Unregistered device 'eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826' [0x4303c7152680]
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)PsaStorEvents: 700: Event Subsystem: Device Events, Destroyed!
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z In(182) vmkernel: cpu4:262523)PsaStorEvents: 700: Event Subsystem: Device Events - Internal, Destroyed!
2022-10-14T02:57:45.567Z Wa(180) vmkwarning: cpu4:262523)WARNING: HPP: HppRegisterDevice:3430: Failed to register device with uid 'eui.3ba5b136f6c441c2a1847041ad8c3826': Not supported
```

We also tried to use NVMe-oF drive with 512K block size, that will work fine and drive can be used as datastore

Do anyone know do vsphere8 support 4K block size NVMe and NVMe-oF ?
And What need to do to setup NVMe and NVMe-oF as datastore if vsphere8 support 4K block size NVMe and NVMe-oF?

Thanks